# Attempting to render Firebase Auth user details through this.setState in React app undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am attempting to render a User's details through Firebase Auth on a 'Profile' page, for them to update if they wish.

I'm attempting to do this within 'componentDidMount', so on page load, using state. However, the function I'm attempting to run is returning the 'this.setState' call as 'undefined'.

This is the error message:

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): undefined is not an object
> (evaluating 'this.setState')

Is there a way to refactor my code to render on page load using firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged?

Here's my component code:

```
class Profile extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

  this.state = {
    displayName: "",
    email: ""
  }
}

  componentDidMount() {

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (!user) {
      this.setState({
        displayName: "",
        email: ""
      })
    } else {
        this.setState({
          displayName: user.displayName,
          email: user.email
        })
    }
  });

  }

onChange = (e) => {
      this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
  }

  render() {

    return (
              <input className="profile-info-type" type="text" name="displayName" value={this.state.displayName || ''} onChange={this.onChange} />

                <input className="profile-info-type" type="email" name="email" value={this.state.email || ''} onChange={this.onChange} />

    )
  }
}
```

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an arrow function for your callback, which will preserve the value of `this` in the outer scope.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    // this.setState()
})
```

Comment: Spot on. Thanks again Doug.